Android - ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener not detached
We encountered a memory leak issue with a listener. Even we remove listener in onDestroyView(), but it remains active and is not properly detached.
We use this listener for hide/show bottombar whenever keyboard is open so if anyone have alternative solution it also work for me OR need to fix leak memory
I would be thankful if anyone give me any suggestion or guidance
--->> HERE is CODE:
// global variable at fragment

private val bottomBarVisibilityLayoutListener = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {

   //...custom code for show/hide bottom bar
   println("Listener call")

}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

 super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
 // Add the listener
 binding.clRoot.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(bottomBarVisibilityLayoutListener)

}


override fun onDestroyView() {

    // Safely remove the listener to avoid memory leaks
    viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(bottomBarVisibilityLayoutListener)
    super.onDestroyView()

}

